# How to remove the active title bar of a frame?

Tags: java, swing, titlebar

I have a JFrame which displays a title bar. Active title bar as it's called in Windows desktop properties. How to remove this bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use setUndecorated(boolean undecorated) method in JFrame.

Note: This method can only be called while the frame is not displayable.

Comment: So it's not possible to hide title bar on click of any button or any other event on screen.

Answer (score 0):

frames have titlebars
windows do not
check out http://academicjava.com/Java_help/Tutorial_Examples_Swing_5.html for examples